# 22.04 LTS - Lenovo IdeaPad Flex 5 Screen doesn't automatically rotate

Tags: 22.04, display-rotation

I just brought the afforementionned laptop, and obviously immediately removed Windows for Ubuntu.

When I choose to rotate my screen, It doesn't want to, but the logo with the disabled touchpad appears.

When I call monitor-sensor, I got this :

```
Waiting for iio-sensor-proxy to appear
+++ iio-sensor-proxy appeared
=== Has accelerometer (orientation: bottom-up)
=== No ambient light sensor
=== No proximity sensor
```

Any hints ? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this issue on my Lenovo Yoga notebook and fixed it. Just write `sudo gedit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf` from your terminal and switch the `#WaylandEnable=false` line to `WaylandEnable=false` (remove the #) . Restart your pc. It will be fixed.

check this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1423578/1642768 and https://askubuntu.com/a/1436429/1642768

Comment: It worked great, thanks !