# Rotate touch screen input to match display rotation on Wayland (Ubuntu 22.04)?

Tags: display, ubuntu-touch, 22.04, touchscreen, wayland

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 on a Raspberry Pi 4. I'm using a touch screen display (display is HDMI, touch is USB) which has a native Portrait orientation. The touch works perfectly out of the box in the native portrait orientation.

I want to use the display in landscape orientation, so I have successfully rotated the display 90° using the Settings -> Displays menu in Ubuntu.

My problem is that the touch input does not rotate to match the display orientation, so my touches correspond to incorrect screen coordinates by 90°. All of the previous answers on this topic are for previous Ubuntu versions that use X, not the latest distro which uses Wayland.

Does anyone know how to achieve this on Ubuntu 22.04?

Many thanks in advance for any help!

*Josh*

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue on my Lenovo Yoga.  Under Wayland, my screen won't automatically rotate when I flip the lid around and switch into tent or tablet mode.

The only way I can get automatic screen rotation is by switching to Xorg when logging in.  With your user selected, a gear will show up in the lower right corner, click on that, and select Ubuntu on Xorg.  I wonder if switching to X will fix your issue, or allow you to fix your issue based on the answers you've seen.

I want to look into this more, to see what the benefits of one windowing system is over the other.  Automatic screen rotation is a benefit of X over Wayland for me.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. Ultimately I want my app to be Wayland-native running inside Ubuntu Frame.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Geoffrey Wagner. Just write `sudo gedit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf` from your terminal and switch the `#WaylandEnable=false` line to `WaylandEnable=false` (remove the #) . Restart your pc. It will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

for right touchscreen rotation i added

Option "TransformationMatrix" "0 1 0 -1 0 1 0 0 1"

to  /usr/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/libinput.conf

to the end of touchscreen section

works permanently after reboot