# Tablet mode on Ubuntu 22.04.1: Problems with Auto rotate, gestures and keyboard

Tags: 22.04, tablet, gestures, display-rotation

questions regarding tablet mode on

HP Elitebook revolve 810
With Ubuntu 22.04.1, fresh intallation

I enabled auto rotate following this guide [Rotate touch screen input to match display rotation on Wayland (Ubuntu 22.04)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1419797/rotate-touch-screen-input-to-match-display-rotation-on-wayland-ubuntu-22-04)

But is there a different solution than going from Wayland to X.org?

Also touch gestures like scrolling, zooming do not work on the screen. They do fine on the touchpad in laptop mode, but not on the touchscreen when in tablet mode. How can I enable it?

Third question: Can I change the virtual keyboard to something more usefull?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to AU. Your third question isn’t really related to the main question - probably better to post something separate rather than combine it with the rest of this post.